# Having Major Difficulties rewriting URL's on Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my URLS' from "/city/?cityid=manhattan" to just "/manhattan".
Or my URL's from "/ads/?cityid=manhattan&ad_category=dogs" to just "/manhattan/dogs".

I am using the folowing codes.

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
global $post;
add_rewrite_rule('^/([^/]*)/','index.php?   
cityid=$matches[1]&page=1205','top'); 
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

My **htaccess** is set as

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cityid=$1&page=1205&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I also need my site titles to read appropriately such as "Manhattan - domain.com"

and also, "Manhattan Dogs - domain.com"

I have been looking for a solution for months and STILL havent been able to change it.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: anyone here ???

Comment: If you remove all the PHP code and inside your `.htaccess` file, then add the following RewriteRule: `RewriteRule ^.*?\?cityid=(\w+)(?:&ad_category=(\w+))?$ $1/$2`

Comment: Let me try this and see what happens

Comment: It's not working :(

Comment: After changing the `.htaccess` file, are you restarting Apache. The server needs to be restarted for the changes to take place.

Comment: Yes, and it still isnt working

Comment: Can someone please help 